# Adding Sound With UIPageViewController iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, uipageviewcontroller

I am new to iOS, and am using PageViewController to set up an app with books. I am having a hard time finding any information on setting up sound with each page. How do you add mp3 files into an array using AVFoundation?

Answer (score 0):

You can play a audio file in background usinf `AVAudioPlayer` u can even play different audio for different page.... Change audio file inside page view controller delegate method, visit this [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/69369/audio-tutorial-ios-playing-audio-programatically-2014-edition) for more detail info